# Recuperar Milissegundos de uma data gravada em um BD MSSQL Server 2019 com VB.Net + ADO.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Gostaria de saber como recuperar uma data como dado dos Milissegundos gravados em um Banco de Dados MS SQL Server 2019 usando o VB.Net + ADO.Net.

Sempre que tento resgatar a data, vem no fomrmato "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" eu gostaria de também ter os ".fff", mas não consigo recuperar esta informação no BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*** código do MODEL:

```
Private _DataAlteracao As DateTime

Public Property DataAlteracao() As DateTime
    Get
        Return _DataAlteracao
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
        _DataAlteracao = value
    End Set
End Property
```

*** Código do INSERT:

```
Public Overloads Function InserirHistorico(entidade As ClsHistoricoDomain) As Object
    Dim objConfirma As Object

    MyBase.LimparStrComando()

    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" INSERT INTO tblHistorico (")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" CNPJ, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" RazaoSocial, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" NomeFantasia, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" CodigoSistema, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" DataAlteracao) ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" VALUES (")
    MyBase.StrComando.Append(IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entidade.CNPJ), String.Format("'{0}',{1}", entidade.CNPJ, Environment.NewLine), "NULL,"))
    MyBase.StrComando.Append(IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entidade.RazaoSocial), String.Format("'{0}',{1}", entidade.RazaoSocial, Environment.NewLine), "NULL,"))
    MyBase.StrComando.Append(IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entidade.NomeFantasia), String.Format("'{0}',{1}", entidade.NomeFantasia, Environment.NewLine), "NULL,"))
    MyBase.StrComando.Append(IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entidade.CodigoSistema), String.Format("'{0}',{1}", entidade.CodigoSistema, Environment.NewLine), "NULL,"))
    MyBase.StrComando.Append(IIf(Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(entidade.DataAlteracao), String.Format("'{0}',{1}", entidade.DataAlteracao, Environment.NewLine), "NULL,"))
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(")")

    objConfirma = SQLHelper.ExecuteScalar(StrComando.Remove(StrComando.ToString.LastIndexOf(","), 1).ToString(), True)

    Return objConfirma
End Function
```

*** Código do SELECT TODOS:

```
Public Overrides Function SelecionarTodos() As List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain)
    MyBase.LimparStrComando()

    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" SELECT CNPJ, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" RazaoSocial, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" NomeFantasia, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" CodigoSistema, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" DataAlteracao ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" FROM tblHistorico ")

    Return MyBase.RetornaLista(StrComando.ToString())
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que montei na 'tblHistorico' uma chave primária composta por dois campos: "CodigoSistema" + "DataAlteracao".

(talvez ajude alguma pessoa)
O melhor que consegui foi fazer o seguinte:

*** Chamada da função para testar

```
Dim strTeste As String

strTeste = GerenciadorBll.Instance.HistoricoBLL.RetornaCodigoHistorico("1", "18-01-2021 15:14:41.897")
mskDataAlteracao.Text = strTeste
```

*** BLL

```
Public Function RetornaCodigoHistorico(Codigo As String, DataHistorico As String) As String
    Return GerenciadorDal.Instance.HistoricoDal.RetornaCodigoHistorico(Codigo, DataHistorico)
End Function
```

*** DAL

```
Public Function RetornaCodigoHistorico(ByVal codigoHistorico As String, ByVal dataHistorico As String) As String
    MyBase.LimparStrComando()

    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" SELECT ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" DataAlteracao ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" FROM tblHistorico ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(String.Format(" WHERE codigoSistema = '{0}' ", codigoHistorico))
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendFormat(" AND DataAlteracao = '{0}' ", dataHistorico)

    Return MyBase.RetornaDataHistorico(StrComando.ToString())
End Function
```

*** BASE DAL

```
Protected Function RetornaDataHistorico(ByVal pCommantText As String) As String
    Dim milliSeconds As Int32
    Dim dt As DateTime
    Dim strTempo As String

    Using dataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLHelper.ExecuteReader(pCommantText)

        If dataReader.HasRows Then
            dataReader.Read()

            dt = dataReader.GetValue(dataReader.GetOrdinal("DataAlteracao"))
            milliSeconds = dt.Millisecond

            strTempo = dt.ToString() + "." + milliSeconds.ToString()
        Else
            Return Now()
        End If

        Return strTempo
    End Using

End Function
```

**Agora ficou um erro quando eu quero um SELECT ALL para preencher um grid...**

*** UI - User Interface

```
Private Sub PreencheGrid(Optional ByVal cod1 As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal cod2 As String = Nothing)

    DgvPadrao.DataSource = Nothing
    DgvPadrao.DataSource = GerenciadorBll.Instance.HistoricoBLL.SelecionarTodos

    If DgvPadrao.Rows.Count > 0 Then
```

...

*** BLL

```
Public Function SelecionarTodos() As List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain) Implements ICrud(Of ClsHistoricoDomain, String).SelecionarTodos
    Return GerenciadorDal.Instance.HistoricoDal.SelecionarTodos()
End Function
```

*** DAL

```
Public Overrides Function SelecionarTodos() As List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain)
    MyBase.LimparStrComando()

    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" SELECT CNPJ, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" RazaoSocial, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" NomeFantasia, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" CodigoSistema, ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" DataAlteracao ")
    MyBase.StrComando.AppendLine(" FROM tblHistorico ")

    Return MyBase.RetornaLista2(StrComando.ToString())
End Function
```

** BASE DAL

```
Protected Function RetornaLista2(ByVal commandText As String, Optional ByVal isSql As Boolean = True) As List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain)

    Dim listaRetorno As List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain) = Nothing

    Try

        If isSql Then
            Using dataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = SQLHelper.ExecuteReader(commandText)
                If dataReader.HasRows Then
                    listaRetorno = New List(Of ClsHistoricoDomain)()
                    While dataReader.Read()
                        Dim objeto As ClsHistoricoDomain
                        objeto = Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(ClsHistoricoDomain), dataReader)

                        listaRetorno.Add(objeto)
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
        End If

        Return listaRetorno

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function
```

**O SELECT ALL JÁ RETORNA TODAS AS DATAS SEM MILISEGUNDOS!!!**

Como na tabela 'tblHistorico' minha chave primária é composta por 'CodigoSistema' + 'DataAlteracao' então eu me ferro, pois retorna vários registros com a informação da Chave Primária Composta INCOMPLETA...

... acho que terei que mudar TODA a lógica de fazer histórico do sistema.... NÃO pode ser uma chave composta com uma data que depende de milissegundos... terá que ser um autonumber ou algo parecido...
... que péssimo, por causa de um erro no código do VB.Net que NÃO retorna os milissegundos em uma busca eu terei que mudar totalmente a minha ideia.